# Collection of collections

Tags: c#, collections

I'm looping over some kind of data set like this:

```
for (...)
{
var a=xxx;
var b=yyy;
var c=zzz;
}
```

I want to insert these variables into a collection.
The result that I want is:

```
myCollection["a"]={xxx1,xxx2,xxx3};
myCollection["b"]={yyy1,yyy2,yyy3};
myCollection["c"]={zzz1,zzz2,zzz3};
```

So that in face, inside the loop, the pseudo code would be something like:

```
for (...)
{
var a=xxx;
var b=yyy;
var c=zzz;
myCollection["a"].append(a);
myCollection["b"].append(b);
myCollection["c"].append(c);
}
```

After the first iteration the collection will look like:
`myCollection["a"] = {xxx1};`
After the second iteration:
`myCollection["a"]={xxx1,xxx2};`

etc...

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myCollection = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
for (...)
{
    if (!myCollection.ContainsKey("a"))
        myCollection.Add("a", new List<string>());
    myCollection["a"].Add("some_item");
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to append items into the collection in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Then you should move declaration of the collection outside the loop.

Comment: This is not the issue. The issue is that I can't append items to an array.

Comment: There is nothing about it in your question. You should clarify the problem statement.